# SQL Query to create edges between multiple vertices at once

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am trying to create a graph in CosmosDB using SQL queries.

I have uploaded a data set to CosmosDB in JSON format. I have a bunch of vertices showing. In my JSON file, I have stored two types of labels: orders and products. Order vertices contain information about the purchased products (see below)

```
{
"id": "o0001",
"label": "Order",
"type": "vertex",
"products": [
    {
        "Product2": 1.0
    },
    {
        "Product3": 1.0
    },
    {
        "Product4": 1.0
    },
    {
        "Product5": 1.0
    },
    {
        "Product6": 1.0
    },
    {
        "Product7": 1.0
    },
    {
        "Product8": 1.0
    },
    {
        "Product24": 1.0
    },
    {
        "Product25": 1.0
    },
    {
        "Product26": 1.0
    },
    {
        "Product27": 1.0
    }
    ]
}

...

{
    "id": "Product02",
    "label": "Product",
    "type": "vertex"
}
...
```

I would like to write an SQL query that connects every order to all the purchased products (i.e. that creates edges between every order and its products). How can I do that for all orders at once, and not just for one specific one?

Answer (score 0):

As i know,there is no such sql could create all edges for all orders at once.Since your order-product structure is affirmatory, i suggest you using [bulk executor lib](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-dot-net#bulk-import-data-to-azure-cosmos-db) with Graph API cosmos db.

Sample code:

```
IBulkExecutor graphbulkExecutor = new GraphBulkExecutor(documentClient, targetCollection);

BulkImportResponse vResponse = null;
BulkImportResponse eResponse = null;

try
{
    // Import a list of GremlinVertex objects
    vResponse = await graphbulkExecutor.BulkImportAsync(
            Utils.GenerateVertices(numberOfDocumentsToGenerate),
            enableUpsert: true,
            disableAutomaticIdGeneration: true,
            maxConcurrencyPerPartitionKeyRange: null,
            maxInMemorySortingBatchSize: null,
            cancellationToken: token);

    // Import a list of GremlinEdge objects
    eResponse = await graphbulkExecutor.BulkImportAsync(
            Utils.GenerateEdges(numberOfDocumentsToGenerate),
            enableUpsert: true,
            disableAutomaticIdGeneration: true,
            maxConcurrencyPerPartitionKeyRange: null,
            maxInMemorySortingBatchSize: null,
            cancellationToken: token);
}
catch (DocumentClientException de)
{
    Trace.TraceError("Document client exception: {0}", de);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Trace.TraceError("Exception: {0}", e);
}
```

Edges Object:

```
// Creating an edge
GremlinEdge e = new GremlinEdge(
    "edgeId",
    "edgeLabel",
    "targetVertexId",
    "sourceVertexId",
    "targetVertexLabel",
    "sourceVertexLabel",
    "targetVertexPartitioningKey",
    "sourceVertexPartitioningKey");

// Adding custom properties to the edge
e.AddProperty("customProperty", "value");
```

You could query all the orders first,then use `Utils.GenerateEdges` method to create edges for every order in the loop.